# Pod identifier number

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to generate a **Unique Key** in the application, using date/time and a number sequence managed by the application. It works fine as we don't have multiapplication.

The application is running in a Kubernetes pod with auto scaling configured.

Is there any way to generate or get a **unique and numeric identifier per pod** and put them in the container environment variables? there is no need for the intentifier to be fixed to use the statefulSets

**UPDATE**

the problem we are having with the uid is the size of the collections, tha's why we're are looking for a solution that's about the size of a bigInt, and if there is any other numberic unique id similar as an alternative of use for the UID.

Comment: doesn't every k8s object already have a uniuqe identifier? i remember the name is something like `uid`.

Comment: thanks for your time @LeiYang! There's indeed a uid as unique identifier, we are hopping to find alternative as a numeric id for alternative use of uid.

Answer (score 2):

`...get a unique and numeric identifier per pod and put them in the container environment variables?`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  labels:
    run: busybox
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    command: ["ash","-c","echo ${MY_UID} && sleep 3600"]
    env:
    - name: MY_UID
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.uid
```

Run `kubectl logs <pod>` will print you the unique ID assigned to the environment variable in your pod.

Comment: thansk for your time @gohm'c! You think there is any other numberic unique id similar as an alternative of use of an UID?

Comment: @lego You can check here for other available metadata: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/

Comment: You can convert the uid to integer and prefix/suffix it with a magic code of your choice to make it universally unique. There are many libraries, tools out there showing how to do this, also explain why plain number alone rarely an unique object.